# Why is the first conditional always returned even when outside of parameter?

Tags: python

Why does this code always return the first conditional even when the input is -1 or -2, and the if statement should only take 0 and above?

```
european_floor = raw_input("Which floor of a Parisian hotel would you like to stay in tonight?")
us_floor = int(european_floor) + 1
lower_us_floor = int(european_floor) - 1

if european_floor > -1:
    print ("For floor " + str(european_floor) + " in Paris, the equivalent floor in New York would be floor " + str(us_floor) + "!")
elif european_floor < -1:
    print ("For floor " + str(european_floor) + " in Paris, the equivalent floor in New York would be floor " + str(lower_us_floor) + "!")
else:
    print ("For floor " + str(european_floor) + " in Paris, the equivalent floor in New York would be the basement!")
```

Comment: You are applying if/elif to the european_floor which is a string. Because, you are converting it into integer only in us_floor and lower_us_floor varibles..try this:  european_floor = int(raw_input("Which floor of a Parisian hotel would you like to stay in tonight?"))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you compare a string to an int. Adjust this line:

```
european_floor = int(raw_input("Which ..."))
```